# Using counters within a PHP loop

Tags: php, wordpress, flexslider

I've using the Flexslider plugin to display a slideshow of three products at a time. The number of products varies from page to page. To ensure the plugin only shows three at a time, I'm using a simple counter:

```
<ul class="slides row">
<li>
    <?php
    $counter = 0;
    while ( have_rows('series_solutions') ) : the_row();
        $counter++;
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-4 series-detail">
        <?php $series_image = get_sub_field('solution_image');
          echo '<img class="img-responsive center-block" src="' . $series_image['url'] . '" alt="' . $series_image['alt'] . '" />';
        ?>
        <span class="series-number"><?php the_sub_field('solution_number');?></span>
        <span class="series-description"><?php the_sub_field('solution_description');?></span>

        <span class="series-screen"><?php the_sub_field('solution_screen_dimensions');?></span>
        <span class="series-body"><?php the_sub_field('solution_body_dimensions');?></span>
        <span class="series-resolution"><?php the_sub_field('solution_resolution');?></span>
        <span class="series-shop"> <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php the_sub_field('solution_spec_sheet_link');?>" target="_blank">Download the Spec Sheet</a>
        </span>
    </div><!-- col-md-4-->
    <?php 
    if ($counter % 3 == 0) {
        echo "</li><li>";
    }?>
    <?php endwhile;?>
</li></ul>
```

The problem is, Flexslider looks for `<li>` elements to determine the start and end of slide content. If a page only has three products, the counter still adds `</li><li>`, which Flexslider interprets as a new—and empty—slide:

[image]

Can that counter be structured in a way that prevents that opening `<li>` from being generated if there's no data to justify it?

Answer (score 0):

Thats a well-known problem i guess. How about this solution (untested but should be like that):

```
  <ul class="slides row">
        <?php
        $counter = -1;
        while ( have_rows('series_solutions') ) : the_row();
            $counter++;

        if ($counter % 3 == 0) {
            echo "<li>";
        }?>
        <div class="col-md-4 series-detail">
            <?php $series_image = get_sub_field('solution_image');
              echo '<img class="img-responsive center-block" src="' . $series_image['url'] . '" alt="' . $series_image['alt'] . '" />';
            ?>
            <span class="series-number"><?php the_sub_field('solution_number');?></span>
            <span class="series-description"><?php the_sub_field('solution_description');?></span>

            <span class="series-screen"><?php the_sub_field('solution_screen_dimensions');?></span>
            <span class="series-body"><?php the_sub_field('solution_body_dimensions');?></span>
            <span class="series-resolution"><?php the_sub_field('solution_resolution');?></span>
            <span class="series-shop"> <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php the_sub_field('solution_spec_sheet_link');?>" target="_blank">Download the Spec Sheet</a>
            </span>
        </div><!-- col-md-4-->
        <?php 
        if ($counter % 3 == 2) {
            echo "</li>";
        endwhile;

if($counter % 3 != 2) {
    echo "</li>";
}

?>
    </ul>
```